# How to run GDB in backround and bring it back?

Tags: bash, job-control, gdb

I'm writing bash scripts that launch a test scenarios: several programs that connect to each other.

If something crashed, I'd like to have a GDB command line.

Looks something like that:

```
myprogram <(cat <<-EOM
    [conf]
    par = abc
EOM
) &>>"$3" &

sleep 1

grep -q DATA <(timeout 5 myclient http://url | tee -a "$3") && exit 0

sleep 5&
wait %+

exit 1
```

I've tried to launch with gdb from the start (using `sleep` as an example application):

```
gdb -ex run --args sleep 30 &
```

And then:

```
fg
```

The `fg` doesn't bring it back properly: can't type anything, SIGINT is strange, shell says that the job is stopped.
Writing `fg` inside the script gives an error `fg: no job control`.

Is there a way?